# Android soft keyboard changing the layout from sample code in sdk

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I wish to change the standard qwerty layout of the android keyboard to something else is there a way of doing that from the sample code available in the android sdk..? I just want to rearrange the keys.. Can somebody please guide me regarding this..?
I am using eclipse Juno

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, you probably will get some downvotes. You should try to googling first and come here if u have problem

Comment: dear sir, i have googled a lot regarding this, read about Android IME, keyboardview comparisons,read Marteen Penning's blog, however i did not find any tutorial/guide by which i can load the sample keyboard code from the sdk and do some changes in it.. i would be glad if you could please help me ..thank you.!